# Ubuntu 20.04 Shutdown/Reboot Hangs At "Waiting for process: crond" And amdgpu process

Tags: 20.04, shutdown, restart, amdgpu

I'm Using Dell 5570 , processor : Intel i5 ,GPU1: Intel 620,  GPU2: AMD 530 , OS : Ubuntu 20.04 Fresh install but this issue comes later after installing and using it for a while
when i press Shutdown/Restart the system stuck on Dell logo for 1 minute then restart/shutdown, so when i press   `Esc` it shows:
[ShutDown/Restart Logs](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ETm0V.jpg)

```
[664.198483] amdgpu : [powerplay] VI should always have 2 performance levels
[666.456075] amdgpu : [powerplay] can't get the mac of 5
[670.450885] systemd-shutdown[1] : waiting for process : crond
[672.138049] amdgpu : [powerplay] VI should always have 2 performance levels
```

Comment: Do you got any solution? If so, please update it. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Same problem on my Xubuntu 20.04 since 2 weeks (installed one year ago on a DELL Inspiron 15 3000 laptop but I think that there is no relation with the hardware) .

In order to find out the origin of this message displayed at shutdown

```
Reached target Reboot.
systemd-shutdown[1]: Waiting for process: crond
```

I used this command to get the `cron` jobs files list (ordered by date) :

```
find /etc/cron* -type f | xargs  ls -ltr
```

I discovered that the file `/etc/cron.d/collect` ( freshly updated ) was scheduling a weird binary named `/var/tmp/crond`.

My solution to disable this job was to move `/etc/cron.d/collect` elsewhere (in my home directory, so as to try before deleting it forever).

After 2 reboots I checked that I recovered a fast shutdown!

(can also follow these links :
https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/644016/465616,
https://askubuntu.com/a/1329933 )

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same problem. When shutdown it displays

> systemd-shutdown [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RjPFP.png): waiting for process: crond

and wait for some time (more than a minute) and it shutsdown.

I'm using **Ubuntu 20.04 LTS**
I googled it and found the solution. I installed Bleachbit from official site: https://www.bleachbit.org/download/linux and link to file: https://www.bleachbit.org/download/file/t?file=bleachbit_4.2.0-0_all_ubuntu2004.deb

**Install:** Just right click it and select Open with other app and select Software install
Or by command line: sudo install < file >

After success install you can see it in Application list, select bleachbit admin and run it.
List is in attachment image(screenshot).
[image]

After this. For First time shutdown it took some time (More than a min) and it did't display any error, and shutdown.

After that everything is normal, now it shutdown fast. I tested many times, it's working good.