# Shutdown problem for cron job /etc/cron.d/collect

Tags: bash, scripts, shutdown, cron, 20.10

For a couple of days now, I'm having shutdown problem in my Ubuntu 20.10 system. Whenever I hit the power Off systemd informs in a moment, `Waiting for process: crond`. After doing some research and reading several manual pages about cron, crontab, anacron etc. I've found the root cause of the problem i.e `/etc/cron/collect`:-

```
*/10 * * * * root /var/tmp/crond
```

invoking journalctl confirms this which had multiple occurrence of `(root) CMD (/var/tmp/crond)`. I've searched a lot on the internet to know if crond was some crucial part of the system and what I understood was that it wasn't crucial. but I wanted to be sure, so I searched everything in system to find a file, which is `/run/crond.pid` which have pid of **cron** in it, not of the process **crond** or specifically of the file `/var/tmp/crond` and To be more certain I've installed ubuntu on gnome-disks and as expected everything I discovered was that there was no `collect` job and there is no `crond` file in **/var/tmp** directory and after all why would anyone sane place a crucial system file in a directory which indicates that it is temporary. But yeah I really don't want to mess up my system and so I'm here to hear that it is safe to delete `/etc/cron.d/collect` and `/var/tmp/crond`. So what do you say?

in response to a comment: `/var/tmp/crond` is a binary executable

Comment: What is `/var/tmp/crond`? is it a binary executable, or a script? if it's a script, what does it contain?

Comment: @steeldriver /var/tmp is binary executable

Answer (score 2):

Same problem on Xubuntu 20.04 since 2 weeks. My system hangs after having displayed :

```
 Reached target Reboot.
 systemd-shutdown[1]: Waiting for process: crond
```

After searching across cron jobs files using this command :

```
find /etc/cron* -type f | xargs  ls -ltr
```

I found 2 potential "culprits" (both have a recent update date):

```
/etc/cron.daily/google-chrome
/etc/cron.d/collect
```

In order to disable them, I moved these files elsewhere (in my home directory) and restarted twice to check.

Great! I recovered the fast shutdown!

PS: The file `/etc/cron.daily/google-chrome` is a script that does not look so bad.
But the file `/etc/cron.d/collect` schedules a weird binary named `/var/tmp/crond` that is not documented.

[This post](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/611031/465616) gave me the way.

Comment: I had the same issue exactly with Kubuntu 20.04 after the installation of some packages and updates. It was took about 100 seconds to shutdown in comparison with about 6 seconds only according to the Plymouth splash theme counter. I found the `collect` task too, and after moving it away from the `/etc/cron.d` everything returned to be fine again.

Comment: Same here. Does anyone know what that collect file does? No problems after moving it.

Answer (score 0):

Just in case anyone comes to this question in the future, on the extremely rare chance:

`/etc/cron/collect` is a file known to belong to an infostealer virus, known by Kaspersky ID `Trojan.Shell.Agent.de`.

If symptoms started after installing Free Download Manager, you unfortunately installed a hijacked copy of Free Download Manager which deployed the aforementioned virus onto your machine.

To disinfect your install, uninstall Free Desktop Manager, delete /etc/apt/sources.list.d/freedownloadmanager.list, /etc/cron.d/collect, /var/tmp/crond, /var/tmp/bs and /var/tmp/atd, restart, then after restarting **change your passwords on any signed in websites** as the virus may have sent your saved browser credentials, etc. to its creators.

More information: https://securelist.com/backdoored-free-download-manager-linux-malware/110465/

https://www.freedownloadmanager.org/blog/?p=664